# Pandas cartesian product filtered by columns of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a csv file with columns img_A, img_B and target values.

**csv 1:**

```
     img_A        img_B   target
    img1.png    img2.png    1
    img1.png    img3.png    1
    img1.png    img4.png    0
    img1.png    img5.png    1
    img6.png    img1.png    0
```

I have another huge csv file containing all images and their feature vectors like:

**csv2:**

```
       img     f1  f2  f3  f4  f5
    img1.png    0   1   0   1   0
```

I need to have a merged feature vector like:

```
     img_A   img_B   f1_A  f2_A  f3_A  f4_A f5_A f1_B f2_B f3_B f4_B f5_B target
   img1.png img_2.png 0    1      0     1     0    0    1    0   1     0   1
```

While my first impression is to get cartesian product by merging the csv2 with itself and later filter it with column combinations in csv1, I am getting memory error since shape of csv2 is around 20000 x 512 and shape of csv1 is around 
75000 x 3.

I tried this:

```
df = df.assign(key=1).merge(df.assign(key=1), on="key", suffixes=["_A", "_B"]).drop("key", axis=1) # memory error
```

While I have tried partitioning the data into chunks it is taking forever to get the result.

Can anyone suggest an optimal way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given dataframes `df1` with `df2`, you can merge twice after renaming columns in `df2`:

```
res = df1.merge(df2.add_suffix('_A'), on='img_A')\
         .merge(df2.add_suffix('_B'), on='img_B')
```

Comment: Wow. That's clever!! Working like a charm. Tysm!!